# Passing a class function as a callback and having this be set in typescript

Tags: typescript

In my express application I have controllers which look something like:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { BooksService } from '../services';

export class BooksController {

  constructor (private booksService: BooksService) { }

  register(router: express.Router) {
    //LINE IN QUESTION
    router.get('/', (req, rsp, next) => this.getBooks(req, rsp, next));
  }

  private getBooks(req: express.Request, rsp: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
    rsp.json(this.booksService.getAllBooks());
  }

}
```

However, I would really like to just write the line in question as:

```
router.get('/', this.getBooks);
```

...but of course then `this` will be undefined.

I can also make `getBooks` a stateless function outside the class:

```
function getBooks(booksService: BooksService) {
  return function(req: express.Request, rsp: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
    rsp.json(booksService.getAllBooks());
  };
}
```

Which allows me to rewrite the line in question as:

```
router.get('/', getBooks(this.booksService));
```

...but that is still a tedious amount of boilerplate, especially if `getBooks` requires access to more than one instance variable.

Is there any way I can pass `this.getBooks` as a callback to express so that `this` will be defined when it is called?  I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: `this.getBooks.bind(this)`? This is JS binding behaviour, nothing to do with TS.

Comment: That works as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `getBooks` as a field of type function, and assign it an arrow function, thus capturing the correct `this`:

```
export class BooksController {

  constructor (private booksService: BooksService) { }

  register(router: express.Router) {
    router.get('/', this.getBooks);
  }

  private getBooks = (req: express.Request, rsp: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    rsp.json(this.booksService.getAllBooks());
  }

}
```

This does have some performance implications, as the function will be created in the constructor, but if you are just going to create an arrow function on each call anyway it should be worse.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks.  I'll accept the answer when I can.